# jquery not working with Dreamweaver template

Tags: jquery, html, dreamweaver

will jquery library not work if its on a template?.. What i want is that when I click a link(video1, video2, video3) the video on a div will change according to the link I clicked. i got this working on a single file but when i put it to a file which is on a template it doesnt work. the video will not load on the div but it goes to the real site of the video.

this one I put it on a template(watch.dwt)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videosource li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#video").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
})
});
</script>
</head>
```

and this one i put on anime1.php which is from watch.dwt template

```
<h2>Beelzebub Episode 1</h2>
<ul id="videosource">   
    <li><a id="island" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53845425">Island in the sky </a></li>
    <li><a id="timelapse" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/C-N9iO0RoVs">Island in the sky </a></li>
    <li><a id="darkside" href="http://www.soul-anime.net/embed/79366.html">Island in the sky </a>                                   </li>

</ul>   
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <IFRAME  id="video" SRC="http://upload4free.co/embed-f7cue4qexcvd-640x360.html" FRAMEBORDER=0  scrolling="no"
    webkitAllowFullScreen ></IFRAME>
      </div>
```

Comment: Look in your console and see if there are any errors. Are you sure the path to the jquery file is right?

Comment: there was no error when I click the first link "island in the sky" the video wont load on the div, it goes directly to the video link

Comment: and the file jquery-1.11.1.min.js is on your root? I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. It's working fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/7ay066kf/

Comment: yes its on my root folder(masite) whre index.php is in.. have sub folders templates folder where watch.dwt is in and watch folder  where anime1.php is in ...i tried that jsfiddle when i click the link nothing happens?